# MongoDB $addToSet any

Tags: mongodb

Can I use any in mongoDB $addToSet?

```js
{ $addToSet: { critters: { id: id_critter, amount: $ }
```

I would like to check if only id_critter is the same, amount can be different.

Comment: No you cannot as that truly would not be a "set". You can only do this by implementing some custom logic that would check all the `id` values within the "critters" sub-document. And typically that means retrieving the document and checking that in code.

Comment: Damn! I thought I'm in home. Thanx for the answer.